# JPGraph linebar can it be done?

Tags: jpgraph

I was trying to make it work with an advanced graph, but since I couldnt find what I needed I am just going to include a basic version so ppl can comment on that.
If someone can help me to get it to work here I can take it from there.

Its a very basic linegraph and I have put a horizontal line in the on the 40 y-axis

What I am after is a line starting in (0,0) and always pointing at 40. Let me try and phrase that better I dont know how long the array is going to be, it will come from a database.
So I want the line to just expand and keep pointing at 40 as the other array grows.

I have included a picture to show what I mean. And sorry for the mistakes I have made english isnt my first language.

Thank you for any help you can give.

Cheers

The Code:

```
<?php // content="text/plain; charset=utf-8"
require_once ('jpgraph/jpgraph.php');
require_once ('jpgraph/jpgraph_line.php');
require_once ("jpgraph/jpgraph_plotline.php");

$datay1 = array(10,15,8,25,34,55);

// Setup the graph
$graph = new Graph(640,480);
$graph->SetScale("textlin");

$theme_class=new UniversalTheme;

$graph->SetTheme($theme_class);
$graph->img->SetAntiAliasing(false);
$graph->title->Set('Filled Y-grid');
$graph->SetBox(false);

$graph->img->SetAntiAliasing();

$graph->yaxis->HideZeroLabel();
$graph->yaxis->HideLine(false);
$graph->yaxis->HideTicks(false,false);

$graph->xgrid->Show();
$graph->xgrid->SetLineStyle("solid");
$graph->xaxis->SetTickLabels(array('A','B','C','D'));
$graph->xgrid->SetColor('#E3E3E3');

$graph->AddLine(new PlotLine(HORIZONTAL,40,"black",1)); 

// Create the first line
$p1 = new LinePlot($datay1);
$graph->Add($p1);
$p1->SetColor("#6495ED");
$p1->SetLegend('Line 1');


$graph->legend->SetFrameWeight(1);

// Output line
$graph->Stroke();

?>
```

http://www.gratisimage.dk/image-1929_5103E42C.jpg